# How to highlight border color of input field when the length of data in input is zero in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```js
      validName: false,

      validateStatus(input) { // will be passed automatically from the template
        if (input.value === 'valid') { // your awesome validation
          this.validName = true;
        } else {
          this.validName = false;
        }
      },

    handleOnChange(value) {
      this.otp_value = value;
    },
```

```html
 <input
                      type="text"
                      name="fullname"
                      id="fullname"
                      v-model="fullname"
                      v-model.trim="$v.fullname.$model"
                      :class="{ 'is-invalid': validName }" 
                      class="input-section"
                      placeholder="Enter your name"
                      @input="validateStatus" 
                    />
```

How to highlight border color if without entering one field if i try to enter data in another field?

At present i am able to highlight the border color, During clicking of input field, But need as after entering some data , Border color should change to normal.

Comment: You can bind your input field class to a `method` that accepts the input field value as a parameter that checks the parameter length and return a class depending on a condition

Comment: @BillJustin I have updated the code as you told, 

But it's not working, Can you please correct me, if there is any code wrong,  So  that it will be very helpful to me.